# Pandas - Column Compare Return False when Nan's are present in both the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am comparing two columns row by row.

It Returns false when NaN's are present in both the columns and I want to return True if Nan's are present.

For Example,

This is the code I am using :-

```
Pre_Out_df[res_name] = Pre_Out_df[plain_col] == Pre_Out_df[b_col]
```

This Returns False for example, when both Columns have Nan for the comparing rows.

Comment: fill nan's with a constant value, like `Pre_Out_df[plain_col].fillna(1) == Pre_Out_df[b_col].fillna(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Check missing or not missing and then [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if both values are `True`s or
[`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check if at least one value is `True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'plain_col':['1A12','1C12',np.nan],
                   'b_col':[np.nan,'1B',np.nan]})


df['res_name1'] = df[['plain_col', 'b_col']].isnull().all(axis=1)
df['res_name2'] = df[['plain_col', 'b_col']].isnull().any(axis=1)

df['res_name3'] = df[['plain_col', 'b_col']].notnull().all(axis=1)
df['res_name4'] = df[['plain_col', 'b_col']].notnull().any(axis=1)

print (df)
  plain_col b_col  res_name1  res_name2  res_name3  res_name4
0      1A12   NaN      False       True      False       True
1      1C12    1B      False      False       True       True
2       NaN   NaN       True       True      False      False
```

Comment: I think, I need something like this - Pre_Out_df[res_name] = Pre_Out_df[plain_col] == Pre_Out_df[b_col] || Pre_Out_df[[plain_col, b_col]].isnull().any(axis=1)

Comment: @Sid29 - Sorry, need `Pre_Out_df[res_name] = (Pre_Out_df[plain_col] == Pre_Out_df[b_col]) | (Pre_Out_df[[plain_col, b_col]].isnull().any(axis=1))` ?

Comment: Small friend advice - try add to your question some sample data and expected output, also your code, what you try for prevent downvotes.

Comment: Will do sir. Thank you.